# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10cb21d98) while running the code

Tags: swift, charts, cocoapods

when i am trying to implement the pod **chart** in my app. its showing the follwing error.

[image]

```
import UIKit

import Charts

class chartViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var barChartView:BarChartView!
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   setupChart(x: months, y: unitsSold)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setupChart(x:[String],y:[Double]){
   var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<x.count{
          let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: y[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    print(chartDataSet)
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    print(chartData)
  barChartView.data = chartData   // here its showing the error

}
```

its showing the error in the last line of code as

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10cb21d98) while running
>   the code

Comment: You need to pass the actual code in question, image is a no go for Stack Overflow. (it's useless for future users)

Comment: Now i  resolved the error. Actually i forget to change the custom class of the view to Barview.

Comment: @Akash Next time, show us the whole error message in debugguer/console. That's the important part where there should have been a "unrecognized selector sent to instance", or a "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" that should tell you that it was the real issue.

Answer (score 12):

1. Select your Storyboard that contains the View Controller with the chart.
2. Select the view that will present the chart.
3. In identity inspector under Custom Class select Bar Chart View in the Class drop down.

That should resolve your problem.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, this is good especially if you have custom classes that you want your UI to follow. It would have taken me a good day to figure this out. Thanks for saving me all that time.

Comment: Trust me... This issue has happened to me so many times it's the first thing I check now.  Cheers!